# Android : Explanation of Proguard Integration

Tags: android, proguard

I've been doing Android development for a little bit and I'm getting to a point in one of my projects where I would like to use Proguard to shrink the size of my APk and help with the dex limit.  Unfortunately, I am getting a few errors and stack overflow has answers but they seem to be targeted for those with more experience.

My question is what is the relationship with your `proguard-android.txt` and `proguard-rules.pro`?  Why are there two separate files and why are they in separate formats?  When are the statements in these files called and in what order?  I am just looking for an explanation of the overall context of using Progurad in a development environment.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: You should take a look at https://developer.android.com/studio/build/shrink-code.html

Answer (score 7, accepted):

ProGuard manipulates Java bytecode the way you tell it with your configuration files and the rules they contain. ProGuard can do many things. And it can completely break your app so you have to make sure to add the correct rules.

I assume you use Gradle based builds for your apps. Then you've probably encountered this snippet that enables ProGuard for release builds of your app (or Android library):

```
android {
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile(‘proguard-android.txt'),
                    'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    ...
}
```

In the config the list `proguardFiles` tells the build what files that contain ProGuard rules it has to use. This list can contain any number of files.

**Why are the files (`proguard-android.txt` and `proguard-rules.pro`) defined differently?**

The magical `getDefaultProguardFile(‘proguard-android.txt')` loads file named `proguard-android.txt` from the standard location in the Android SDK (the location is `${ANDROID_SDK}/tools/proguard/`).

Other config files are resolved locally, so file `proguard-rules.pro` is expected to be at the root of the current Gradle module.

**Why are there two separate files? And what is the relationship between `proguard-android.txt` and `proguard-rules.pro`?**

ProGuard configuration is additive. You can define some rules in one file and other in other files. The rules are internally concatenated into single list of rules.

File `getDefaultProguardFile(‘proguard-android.txt')` contains several general rules for all Android apps (check them yourself, in the file in your SDK). The local `proguard-rules.pro` is expected to contain rules specific for your own app. For example you want to make sure that a class is not stripped away when you use it only through reflection (I'll get to that later).

Note that having multiple local files is very useful. For example you can use two local config files for debug builds - one with the release rules for your app and the second containing rules disabling obfuscation.

Also note that the additive behaviour of the configurations can be a bit troubling. If you add a rule in one config file, you cannot remove it in another. So be careful with very general rules (e.g. imagine adding `-keep class ** { *; }`).

**When are the statements in these files called and in what order?**

You can define them in any order, there's no difference. And you can define the same rule in multiple files, it doesn't matter. The order of the specified files doesn't matter either.

ProGuard itself is run as a single job within the Android build (single Gradle task to be precise). The task is provided all the inputs:

- classes to manipulate
- library classes to use but not manipulate
- output path for generated processed jar
- ProGuard rules specifying the manipulation
- output paths for various output information (what was removed, mapping, …)

And then it processes the files and generates an output which is further processed by the Gradle build.

**How does ProGuard actually work? And why do I need the rules?**

ProGuard traverses the whole call graph of classes/methods/fields/…. It starts with the classes/methods/… defined by the provided rules. Then traverses the call graph and marks classes/methods/fields/… as necessary and keeps them for the output. So if you call it with no matching keep rules it will generate an empty output (or maybe it will throw an error and tell you to define some, I don't remember now). ProGuard doesn't recognize calls done via reflection, so you have to add some rules to handle that. There are many other cases that require you to add some rules, check the [documentation](http://proguard.sourceforge.net/) for that.

**Final notes**

If you check [ProGuard documentation](http://proguard.sourceforge.net/) you can find various rules
you can use. But not all of the rules are good for Android (ProGuard is a general Java tool).

Some rules are generated by Android build itself, you don't have to define them yourself. There are 2 types of such rules:

1. General config rules like `-injars`, `-libraryjars`, …
2. Rules generated from `AndroidManifest.xml` and resources (layouts). Android build (aapt tool) generates rules to keep classes mentioned in the manifest (activities, services, receivers, …) and custom views used in layouts. You can check these generated rules in `build/intermediates/proguard-rules/${PRODUCT_FLAVOR}/${BUILD_TYPE}/aapt_rules.txt`

Some rules can come from **aar** libraries. The libraries can contain ProGuard config necessary for the library to work (there can be  `proguard.txt` file inside).

When writing Android libraries yourself be extremely careful with the rules you want to add to the aar. Because of the additive nature of the rules, it can cause problems for the app that bundles the library.

Comment: Hi thanks for the answer! Should we explicitly add rules from **build/intermediates/proguard-rules/${PRODUCT_FLAVOR}/${BUILD_TYPE}/aapt_rules.txt** to proguard-rules.pro? Or proguard automatically adds this files to their config when building?

Comment: It's not necessary. Those should be added implicitly by the build.